# Can't get values from URL rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to get some values from my rewritten URL:

```
localhost/POO/Project/potato/cheese
```

What I'm expecting to get (dumping the `$_GET` variable)

```
array(1) { ["url"]=> "potato/cheese" }
```

What I'm getting now

```
array(1) { ["url"]=> string(0) "" }
```

I'm working on XAMPP on windows 10

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews -Indexes
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On

        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php?url=$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

`mod_rewrite` is enabled in my PHP.

Comment: Your last `RewriteRule` has no capture groups so `$1` will not be set

Comment: As @Phil commented you need to actually capture part of or all of the path in the incoming request to be able to cite it using the place holder `$1`. So that last rule _probably_ should read something like `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]`...